# Oracle - number of referencing columns must match referenced columns

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table Supplier(
SuppId number(5),
SuppName VARCHAR2(15),
Suppaddress VARCHAR2(50),
SuppCity VARCHAR(15),
Supppostcode number(4),
SuppPhone VARCHAR(15),
CONSTRAINT pk_supplier PRIMARY KEY (SuppId)
);

create table Item(
ItemId  number(5),
Itemname VARCHAR2(15),
Size1 VARCHAR2(4),
Color VARCHAR2(10),
price number(4),
numstock number(3),
CONSTRAINT pk_item PRIMARY KEY (ItemId)
);

create table Supplier_Item(
suppquantity number(3),
SuppId number(5),
ItemId  number(5),
CONSTRAINT pk_supplier_item PRIMARY KEY (SuppId, ItemId),
CONSTRAINT fk_supplier_item FOREIGN KEY (SuppId, ItemId)
REFERENCES Supplier(SuppId)
References Item(ItemId)
);
```

This is the error I'm getting.

> ORA-02256: number of referencing columns must match referenced columns

I don't really understand how to fix this error, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstood how the `foreign key` clause works.

You need to specify each FK constraint on its own. You can't combine them into one:

```
create table Supplier_Item
(
  suppquantity number(3),
  suppid       number(5),
  itemid       number(5),
  CONSTRAINT pk_supplier_item PRIMARY KEY (suppid, itemid),
  FOREIGN KEY (suppid) references supplier (suppid), 
  foreign key (itemid) references item (itemid)
);
```

Or if you want to give both FKs a name:

```
create table Supplier_Item
(
  suppquantity number(3),
  suppid       number(5),
  itemid       number(5),
  CONSTRAINT pk_supplier_item PRIMARY KEY (suppid, itemid),
  constraint fk_supp_item2supplier foreign key (suppid) references supplier(suppid), 
  constraint fk_supp_item2item foreign key (itemid) references item (itemid)
);
```

Comment: I have to wait 3 more minutes to approve the answer @XING :) EDIT: Ahh i see, my bad, I'll keep that in mind for next time!

Comment: You can also include single-column FKs as part of the column definition and let them inherit their parent's datatype: `suppid constraint supplier_item_supplier_fk references supplier`

Answer (score 1):

This is the part where you have an error:

```
CONSTRAINT fk_supplier_item FOREIGN KEY (SuppId, ItemId)
REFERENCES Supplier(SuppId)
References Item(ItemId)
```

You need to create separate foreign keys, like this:

```
CONSTRAINT fk_supplier_item_supplier FOREIGN KEY (SuppId) REFERENCES Supplier(SuppId),
CONSTRAINT fk_supplier_item_item FOREIGN KEY(ItemId) References Item(ItemId)
```